# Why does Controller inherit from ControllerBase on GitHub but not in VS?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

When pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> (Go To Definition) on `Controller` in Visual Studio it shows you the abstract base class.

```cs
public abstract class Controller : IActionFilter, IFilterMetadata, IAsyncActionFilter, IDisposable
```

But when looking up [Controller.cs on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs). It shows that it inherit from [`ControllerBase`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs).

```cs
public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase, IActionFilter, IAsyncActionFilter, IDisposable
```

Why is this?

I am confused. Also, since `HomeController` inherit from `Controller` how can `Controller` inherit from `ControllerBase` when C# does not support multiple inheritance?

Comment: Controller is only inheriting ControllerBase class rest are interfaces

Comment: @brykneval, yes but `HomeController` inherits from ´Controller` which in turn inherits from `BaseController`. But maybe that isn't multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are from different points in time.  So for example the file you linked to on GitHub is the current version of the file, note that it's from the Dev branch.

[image: dev branch]

And more than likely you are not running code from the current dev branch.

If you click on the history button on GitHub for the file you linked to you will see the revision history for the file.

[image: Revision history]

I checked the various version of this file by clicking on the <> button for each revision but non match the version of the code you are running.  I see that the revision history for this file only goes back to Jan 22 2016.  So prior to that the Controller code must have been defined in a different file or for some other reason the revision history was lost (Possibly when they renamed it from MVC 6 to Core MVC 1.0).

More than likely you are running code from RC1.  That version of the Controller.cs on GitHub more closely matches what you are seeing: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs It should match perfectly if it's the right version of the code but I see that it's still slightly different.  It matches in the sense that it does not inherit from `ControllerBase`.

[image: rc1 version of the code]

Also with regard to multiple inheritance.  When HomeController inherits from Controller and Controller inherit from ControllerBase that's not multiple inheritance.  Multiple inheritance would be if there were a ControllerBase and let's say a SomethingElse class and the Controller inherited from both of these classes in the controller definition.  You are correct that C# does not support this.